# I was claimed as a dependent in 2018 but not in 2019

Tags: united-states, income-tax, covid-19, stimulus

I filed my own taxes in 2019 as a single. In 2018, I was claimed as a dependent by my parents, but they haven’t filed their 2019 taxes. Will I still receive a stimulus check?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already filed your own 2019 tax return, and on that return you did not check the "Someone can claim You as a dependent" box, then you should be receiving the stimulus payment (assuming you meet the income threshold requirements).