# Stimulus and dependent question

Tags: stimulus

For the 2018 tax year, I let my parent claim my daughter and I as dependents. However, I filed for the 2019 tax year and claimed myself and my daughter.

My mother received her stimulus and an extra $500 - I presume it was for my daughter because I’m well over 17.

Does this mean I won’t receive the stimulus, since I was claimed as a dependent for 2018 taxes, even though I filed for 2019?

Also, if I do receive $1700 (for myself and my child) would my parent have to pay back the extra $500 they received?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I was claimed as a dependent in 2018 but not in 2019](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124004/i-was-claimed-as-a-dependent-in-2018-but-not-in-2019)

Comment: @Daniel that does appear to answer the part of the question relating to the OP, and while I do agree [we need a cononical *who is eligible* question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2863/cares-act-tax-refund-eligibility-questions), I don't think we have any existing questions that cover the daughter's case (claimed as dependent by different filers in different years - who gets the credit?).

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for the link, however it leaves out whether I’ll receive a stimulus at all. I’ll provide a bit more info. My parent hasn’t yet filed for 2019. They receive SSDI and automatically received their stimulus. Since they claimed me in addition to my child (and the IRS must have gone off of her 2018 taxes because she received the add’l $500) I’m suspecting that I was considered a dependent too and therefore won’t receive a stimulus, even though I’ve already filed for the 2019 tax year.

Comment: That said, I know we don’t have all the answers yet and I’m just looking for guidance/similar situations. I appreciate everyone’s time and assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my reading of the law, if they processed your 2019 tax return early enough to use your 2019 tax return instead of 2018 as the basis for the stimulus advance payment ("check"), you *will* receive the $500 for your daughter, since you rightfully claimed her as a dependent on your 2019 tax return. However, it is not clear which 2019 tax returns that have already been filed will be used, as some people who have filed 2019 tax returns report deposit amounts that seem to be based on their 2018 tax return.

If that happened, your mother would *not* have to pay back any amount of her check, since it was correct based on her 2018 tax return, on which she rightfully claimed your daughter as a dependent. Even if your mother does not claim your daughter as a dependent on her 2020 tax return, and therefore she would qualify for a smaller amount for 2020 tax year than she got in the check, she would not have to pay back the difference.

Comment: Would the mother have a reduced refund if she didn't qualify for the $500 in 2020?

Comment: @Nosjack: No, the mother wouldn't have any less refund or owe more taxes on her 2020 tax return. She will simply get 0 additional tax credit because she did not qualify for more based on 2020 than she got in the check, but the law says the credit will not be negative (meaning she having to pay back money) if the qualifies for less based on 2020 than she got in the check.